# Testing the SharpSnmpLibrary

Tags: snmp, sharp-snmp

I have to test the class Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Pipeline.ISnmpContext with the following methods

get_Binding 
get_CreatedTime 
get_Request 
get_Response 
get_Sender

but not a unit test, i need a test case and i should not modify the library itself but only using it. I thought about using the snmptrapd already in the code examples but i have no idea how to call in particular those methods above without modifying the library and i cannot find any example.I see there is something in the Rolling Logger in the GetLogEntry method but as said i need help to get an Isnmp context first

Thanks

Comment: `ISnmpContext` is an interface, not a class. Thus, I could not understand what you plan to do with it. If you are writing a test case, and need to use such a context, you either create an instance of `NormalSnmpContext`, or `SecureSnmpContext`, or simply create a mock using mocking framework such as moq.

Comment: I have a question.How is it possible to be in the case of an ExceptionRaisedEventArgs? I mean is that possible to get it only using the snmpdiscover and the snmpd?In which case?  I Need to use as well the GetTable.The SysOrTable would be a good example but i cannot get it when inserting the SysOrTable OID.What am i missing? Thanks for the very useful support

Comment: I could not understand what you are going to do. Maybe you can open a new question and type more about what is the problem.